# Get argument from string starting with "name:"

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I have:

```
String query = IRON_SWORD 1 name:&aMagic_Iron_Sword lore:&5Magic|is|amazing sharpness:10 hide_enchants
```

I split it into args:

```
String[] args = s.split(" ");
```

Now how do I get the argument starting with `name:` **Note, I don't mean getting it with `args[2]` because the name could be the 5th or 4th arg.**

Comment: Why do `s.replace(" ", ",");
String[] args = s.split(",")` instead of simply `String args = s.split(" ")`?

Comment: Oh, I have no idea why I did that.

Comment: So is the expected result `&aMagic_Iron_Sword` or `Magic_Iron_Sword`?

Comment: What language is this? I assume C++?

Comment: Java and expected result is &aMagic_Iron_Sword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three approaches come to mind:

1. Search your split results for the element that `startsWith()` "name", then split that and get the element at index 1.
2. Utilize `String.indexOf()` and `String.substring()` to exact what you're looking for
3. Use `regex` pattern `"name:(\\S*) "` and capture the data you want into group 1

Examples of these approaches:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String query = "IRON_SWORD 1 name:&aMagic_Iron_Sword lore:&5Magic|is|amazing sharpness:10 hide_enchants";

    System.out.println(getNameSplit(query));
    System.out.println(getNameSubstring(query));
    System.out.println(getNameRegex(query));
}

public static String getNameSplit(String query) {
    String[] pieces = query.split(" ");
    for (String piece : pieces) {
        if (piece.startsWith("name")) {
            return piece.split(":")[1];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static String getNameSubstring(String query) {
    int nameIndex = query.indexOf("name:");
    int spaceIndexAfterName = query.indexOf(" ", nameIndex);
    // +5 to skip name:
    return query.substring(nameIndex + 5, spaceIndexAfterName);
}

public static String getNameRegex(String query) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("name:(\\S*) ").matcher(query);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Results:

```
&aMagic_Iron_Sword
&aMagic_Iron_Sword
&aMagic_Iron_Sword
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using `getNameSplit`

Comment: @Danielngx-development You're welcome.  You don't have to change your selected answer, but an up vote would be nice if my answer helped out. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The regex `\sname:(\S*)` will successfully find it in the larger string (without the `split` call).

Here's sample code:

```
    String s = "IRON_SWORD 1 nme:&aMagic_Iron_Sword lore:&5Magic|is|amazing sharpness:10 hide_enchants";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\sname:(\\S*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String name = m.group(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use regex.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\bname:)\\S+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: What if `String` doesn't contain `name:` it would break right?

Comment: code inside the `{}` would be executed only if the match occurs.

Comment: Why not use `if (m.find);` then?

Comment: what if you have more than one `name` tags?

Answer (score 0):

What about trying:

```
foreach args as find
{
    searched = split (find, ":")
    if searched[0] == 'name' 
    {
         result = searched[1]
    }
}
```

I dont know what language you are using but I am sure you could adapt.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add language. Java.

Comment: Dont know much about java but must be anyway of looping trough all the args and splitting them all using the ":" and then if the first part of the split is matching the string "name" then the second part is the part you are looking for.